# *ngIf is not working

Tags: angular

i am using **angular 2 RC 4** and *ngIf is not working here is the code for view

**View**

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <span class="navbar-brand"> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Home</a>
        <span style="color:red">{{auth.isAdmin}}</span>
        <span style="color:red">{{auth.isLoggedIn}}</span>
        </li>
        
        <li *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn && auth.isAdmin"><a [routerLink]="['/Category']">Category</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn && auth.isAdmin"><a [routerLink]="['/Products']">Product</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn && !auth.isAdmin"><a [routerLink]="['/BuyProduct']">Buy Products</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn && !auth.isAdmin"><a [routerLink]="['/Cart']"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="badge" >11</span></a></li>
        <!--<li *ngIf="isLoggedIn"><a [routerLink]="['/Folder']"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="badge" >Folder</span></a></li>-->
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn">
        <!--<li><a href="#">{{isLoggedIn}} b</a></li>-->
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Register']">Register</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Login']">Login</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn">
        <!--<li><a href="#">{{isLoggedIn}} a</a></li>-->
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Welcome {{auth.userName}}</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Login']" (click)="logOut()" >Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container ">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <hr />
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; My ASP.NET Application</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router'
import {  OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
//import '../../public/css/styles.css';

import {CategoryComponent} from './category.component';
import {ProductComponent} from './product.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import {BuyProductComponent} from './buyproduct.component';
import {CartComponent} from './cart.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register.component';
import {FolderComponent} from './folder.component';

import { AuthService }         from '../services/auth.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '../views/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  //it's bcoz of this error Component not found in precompile array.
  precompile: [CategoryComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BuyProductComponent,
    CartComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    FolderComponent
  ],
  
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    ////debugger;
    //console.log("in ngOnInit"); 
    this.auth = this.authService.getAuthData();
  }

  auth: any = {};
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    console.log("in constructor");
    console.log('calling auth data from constructor');
    authService.authChanged$.subscribe(value => {
      console.log("from authchange");
      this.auth = value;
      console.log(value);
    });


    console.log("from app component " + authService.auth.isLoggedIn);
  }
  title = "App Component";

  logOut()
  {
    this.authService.resetAuthData();
  }
}
```

**Screen shot in browser**

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working to me... Since isLoggedIn is currently set to false the only thing that should be showing is the "Register" and "Login" links.

Comment: sorry for wrong screen shot please check now

Comment: Can you log the value of the `auth` field in the AppComponent?

Comment: if u check the view i am logging both values i am concerned with

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this way -

```
*ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn == true"
```

I know it is weird , but it worked for me

Comment: :D , You know I discovered it yesterday and now I got some points. Weird things are good :D :p

Comment: i hope it will be fixed in final release

Comment: it does'nt work for the other case i think two condition with the same statement is not working in ngIf is not working so i combine two of them in to one in component to get rid of this angular2 bug

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately for me, the issue was that I forgot to import the BrowserModule or CommonModule. I'm working with Angular 9 and spent over 30 minutes looking for what wasn't lost.

Comment: In my case I forgot to import the CommonModule. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue the `CommonModule` was not imported.

Comment: Ahhh yes!!!!!! Thank you that CommonModule!

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that you have spelling right i.e. `ngIf` **not** `ngif` or `ngIF` etc.

Comment: Damnit! Thank you, was about to break my laptop!

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have declared the component in the module.ts file.

I was also working on an existing project and some times where my *ngIf DIRECTIVE was not working [ngIf directive not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLbsn.jpg)
even I have added the correct syntax in my .ts file[added the correct declaration still it was not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSxgz.png)
after few hour I checked the declaration and declared the component in the module.ts file.[declared the component in module.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF7Ho.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this kind of issue,

I figured it out that result I was checking was with UpperCase.

So, ex: `auth.isLoggedIn` returns `True`, and when `*ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn"` equals it, it goes like this `*ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn === true"` and this never return expected result.

Check if `auth.isLoggedIn` returns lowercase  `true` or `false` without double quotes (not `"true"`), or is `boolean` type!.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If *ngIf is not working when you load a component with **ModalController**, verify you imported the component module into the host module.

```
// Make sure you import MyComponent into your host component. 
 modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
          component:  MyComponent,
          componentProps: { id: id }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these three possibilities. Extended the answer of Mr.pd farhad

```
*ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn == true"
```

Or

```
*ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn != true"
```

Or

```
*ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn == false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the function declaration by:

```js
functionName = () => this.valid = true
```

before it was

```js
functionName(){ this.valid = true }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had gone through the same scenario
main-component.ts (bootstrap component)

```
<h1 *ngIf="isNav">Strangely this will display</h1>
<div *ngIf="isNav">
    <h1>This text will not display even though isNav is true</h1>
    <navbar></navbar>
</div>
```

When I checked properly Inside the navbar ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook there was an error related to the subscription. After solving that ng-if was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hade same problem with **Inonic** component. I've created new module for component and forgot to import **CommonModule**.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule], <- here
  declarations: [PickupCallCardComponent],
  exports: [PickupCallCardComponent],
})
export class PickupCallCardModule {}
```