# angular2 - show hide if value is empty

Tags: angular

Here I have two container, first container suppose to be show if value is exist in json and second one show is value is empty from json. Here is my code:

**App.component.html**

```
<!-- show this container if value is exist -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="outletName">
  <div class="media media-xs align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="media-right float-right">
      <a class="drop-assigned-outlet" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary-ln" *ngIf="outletName">Change assigned outlet</button>x
  </div>
</ng-container>

<!-- show this container if value is empty -->
<ng-container *ngIf="outletName == ''">
  <div class="media media-xs align-items-center mb-5">
    <p>No outlet have assigned</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary-ln">Assign an outlet</button>
</ng-container>
```

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "staffId": "59998eeadfb23a8c0bba5769",
    "staffName": "Sutton Fitzpatrick",
    "outletName": "Marjorie Fitzgerald",
    "outletId": "59998eeaf84372166a233235",
    "outletLocation": "mid valley, kl",
    "designation": "Outlet Supervisor",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/100x100",
    "activeSince": "2015-06-27T09:29:23 -08:00",
    "deactivatedSince": "2015-12-07T12:05:04 -08:00",
    "status": "active",
    "email": "samuelkavin@yahoo.com",
    "contact": 60124174701,
    "devices": [
      {
        "posName": "Outlet1_DEVICE00001",
        "deviceId": "59998eea245ec74623bfb06c",
        "lastActive": "04:50:34"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

    let staffDetail = localStorage.getItem('editStaff');
    let staff = JSON.parse(staffDetail);

    this.outletName = staff.dataItem.outletName;
    this.outletLocation = staff.dataItem.outletLocation;
    this.image = staff.dataItem.image;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual behavior? What is the expected behavior? Is `outletName` actually an empty string (`''`) when doesn't exist, or is it `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes `outletName` is empty string if no value. There are two `ng-container` in template and first `ng-container` suppose to be show if `outletName: 'something'` and second one show if `outletName: ''`

Comment: Please add the .ts file of the component, especially the part where you assign the values from the json to the properties of the component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your previous answer is already worked prefectly to me but you deleted. I've updated my .ts as well

Comment: Interesting. This has to be some Angular-specific behavior, because in plain JS `''` is falsey, but glad to hear that it works for you anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401817/ngif-is-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the first to

```
<ng-container *ngIf="outletName !== ''">
```

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer

Answer (score 2):

Here you have 'perfect' occasion to use **ng-templates**:

```
 <div *ngIf="outletName; else templateForEmpty">
          <div class="media media-xs align-items-center mb-5">
              <div class="media-right float-right">
                 <a class="drop-assigned-outlet" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
              </div>
             <button class="btn btn-primary-ln" *ngIf="outletName">Change assigned outlet</button>x
           </div>
           <ng-template #templateForEmpty>
              <div class="media media-xs align-items-center mb-5">
                 <p>No outlet have assigned</p>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary-ln">Assign an outlet</button>
           </ng-template>
   </div>
```